# Ansible update existing hash values for custom keys

Tags: ansible

Trying to find a solution for this task: I have a role with default values. For example - here are them:

```
some_hash:
  name1:
    some_attr: some_val
    some_extra_args: ''
    limits:
      max: 1
      min: 2
  name2:
    some_attr: some_val
    some_extra_args: ''
    limits:
      max: 10
      min: 5
  ...
```

This role is working as expected and it is enough for 99% of usage cases. But sometimes I need to run this role with the same values except `min` and `max`. In these rare cases I need to have `min` and `max` to equal 0 for all cases in this hash.

First of all I thought about adding an additional task (with tag `never` and some additional tag to execute this part) which will have `include_vars` and additional file where I will set all `min` and `max` to 0.

But in this case in the future I will need to keep updated at least 2 files: default vars and my custom vars which is not good.

Does Ansible has some filter to update values in hash dynamically? Example of what I need in rare cases:

```
some_hash:
  name1:
    some_attr: some_val
    some_extra_args: ''
    limits:
      max: 0
      min: 0
  name2:
    some_attr: some_val
    some_extra_args: ''
    limits:
      max: 0
      min: 0
  ...
```

And this conversation should be applied before tasks:

```
- name: Assemble config
  assemble:
    src:  "some_path"
    dest: "some_path.j2"

- name: Templating
  template:
    src: "path_from_asseble_above.j2"
    dest: ...

...
```

Maybe it is possible with `set_fact` task and some ansible filters/convertations?

Comment: Can you clarify where you're *using* these values? You've shown an `assemble` task, but `assemble` doesn't do any templating (for that you'd need the `template` module).

Comment: @larsks Yeah, you are right, next task after `assemble` is  `template`, which is using `dest` from `assemble` in `src` in `template`. Sorry for this confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```yaml
  some_hash:
    name1:
      limits:
        max: "{{ rare_case|d(1) }}"
        min: "{{ rare_case|d(2) }}"
    name2:
      limits:
        max: "{{ rare_case|d(10) }}"
        min: "{{ rare_case|d(5) }}"
```

expands by default to

```yaml
  some_hash:
    name1:
      limits:
        max: '1'
        min: '2'
    name2:
      limits:
        max: '10'
        min: '5'
```

In the rare case the dictionary expands to

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e rare_case=0

  ...

  some_hash:
    name1:
      limits:
        max: '0'
        min: '0'
    name2:
      limits:
        max: '0'
        min: '0'
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan! Will check and update this post